# Force CSS file to reload after jquery event

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to force the CSS file to reload after a jquery event? i.e.

css file has in it:

```
 .someclass{
 font-size:2em;
 font-family:courier;
 etc...
 }
```

Jquery event(s):

```
 $('#myid').append('<td class="someclass">stuff...</td>
```

Comment: What is your current problem? What do you want to achieve with this reloading?

Comment: why would you want to reload your css if it hasn't changed.

Comment: if you want the `td` element you're appending to have the `someclass` class after you append it, it will. you don't need to reload your CSS file

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to add an element to the DOM, any style designated in a STYLE block or in an attached CSS file that is matched by a valid stylesheet selector should automatically affect that element. You do not need to reload the attached stylesheet.

For instance (demo):

```
.someclass {
    background-color: #f00;
    padding: 5px;
}

<table id="myid">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Adjacent to added TD</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('#myid tbody tr').append('<td class="someclass">stuff...</td>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5WLnX/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changing your css file, you should not force a javascript reload of it (if that is possible even). when you create new elements (ex: with `append()`) all css is applied to it automatically.

Answer (score -1):

It is automatically applied on your `<td>`, there is no need to reload it or so...